# Create a date range serie with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a start date and a finish date for several people :

```
# input df    
df_input = pd.DataFrame([
        ["John", "2018-08-03", "2018-08-05"],
        ["Jack", "2018-08-20", "2018-08-21"]
])
df_input.columns = ["name", "start_day", "finish_day"]
```

I want to create a date range for every people (I want a pd.Series that contains date range) :

```
# output df
df_output = pd.DataFrame([
    ["John", "2018-08-03", "2018-08-05", "['2018-08-03', '2018-08-04', '2018-08-05']"],
    ["Jack", "2018-08-20", "2018-08-21", "['2018-08-20', '2018-08-21']"]
])
df_output.columns = ["name", "start_day", "finish_day", "date_range"]
```

I don't know how to create that range.
Any idea ?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Check the apply functionality - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: my expected output is df_output. I wrote the code to create both of the input and output df. My question is : what methods do I need to use to create my output df from the input one ?

Comment: Use date_range method whereever you cant to create a date range.           dates = pd.DataFrame({
                      'DateCol' : pd.date_range('2018-01-01','2019-12-01',freq='M'),
                       'count' : np.random.randint(5,size=23)
                     }
                     )

Comment: I tried to do df["range"] = pd.date_range(df["start_day"],df["finish_day"],freq='D') but it didn't worked

Comment: This is definition of date_range, it does not accept dataframe. Signature: pd.date_range(start=None, end=None, periods=None, freq='D', tz=None, normalize=False, name=None, closed=None, **kwargs)
Docstring:
Return a fixed frequency DatetimeIndex, with day (calendar) as the default
frequency

start : string or datetime-like, default None
    Left bound for generating dates
end : string or datetime-like, default None
    Right bound for generating dates
periods : integer, default None
    Number of periods to generate
)

Comment: Have you got the solution, or I should add anything else.

Comment: I don't have the solution. Is there a way I can use an apply method and convert pd.date_range to a list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Challanging and interesting one! I think the following snippet gets pretty close to what you are asking, though the shape is a little different from the exact output you requested. Yet, the restructured shape of the output does contain the range of dates, the name and the end date.

```
import pandas as pd
df_input = pd.DataFrame([["John", "2018-08-03", "2018-08-05"],["Jack", "2018-08-20", "2018-08-21"]], columns=['Name','Start_Date','End_Date'])
df_input['Start_Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df_input['Start_Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df_input['End_Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df_input['End_Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df_input.set_index('Start_Date', inplace=True)
def reindex_by_date(df_input):
    dates = pd.date_range(df_input.index.min(), df_input['End_Date'].min())
    return df_input.reindex(dates).ffill()
finaldf = df_input.groupby('Name').apply(reindex_by_date)
finaldf
```

Comment: Great, the shape is a little different from what I wanted but it does the job :)